# Path issue with PHP Dotenv

Tags: php, phpdotenv

Im new to this, and have been trying for a few hours to get this to work. I have a project with this structure:

```
/API
    -.env
    /Processor
        -index.php
```

The contents of my .env file is this:

```
API_KEY=xxxx
```

and in my index.php file

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../');
$dotenv->load();
$client = Client::withApiKey($_ENV['API_KEY']);
```

It works if I replace $_ENV['API_Key'] with the actual key, so I believe the rest of the setup is correct. I feel like Im missing the correct path to the .env file - how do I check and or fix?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv), you shouldn't use the constructor directly. It looks like the usual usage is `Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__.'/../');` which returns an object you then call `->load()` on

Answer (score 3):

You are using Dotenv wrong. It has a static function to create instance.

```
 $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ . '\..');
 $dotenv->load();
```